# Diagnostic Menu (like IFTTT)

Tags: javascript, html, css, magento

I am looking for a unique way for my magento store to display products based on a customers input to a predetermined menu. Similar to an IFTTT -- so for example: customer would select the model of their device, then content would be displayed as such that they would then have another set of options to select what issue they might be experiencing. Then when they select the issue, it would display the product(s) they would need to purchase in order to fix the device.. So really this would be an IFTTT menu that would work on a single page without any loads -- I appreciate any feedback or resources that can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular for making the application without page load.

 Or

You can built ajaxify the whole page.

Make a page that accept the userinput and based on the input send request to get the collection and filter the collection using the input got from the customer. Make sure all the input that you are taking from the customer should be the attributes of the product then only you can filter the collection using AddAttributeToFilter.

After getting the collection and show them resulting collection and if you need further filtration then do the same thing repeatedly and should the collection.